# Algorithm for prioritize list of number (balloting)

Tags: algorithm

I am implementing an algorithm for prioritizing a list of number, and based on the reference code, the logic is,

1. Prepare a list for assigning priority no. (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
2. Assign random number using random number generator to the numbers above
3. Sort the list by the assigned random number (e.g. 3, 2, 5, 1, 4)
4. Then from the reference sources, it assigns the priority no. to the list as

index = (random_number mod number_no_priority_count) + 1

random_number - last output value of step (2)
number_no_priority_count = Total number of records with no priority no. assigned

then assign the priority no. to the record with sorting index in (3) (e.g. if index = 3, assign priority no. = 1 to element 3, i.e. number 5)

I have several reference codes have similar logic above, might anyone advise if step (4) is a standard algorithm?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What are priority numbers for?

Comment: I don't understand the description. Could you include a completely worked out example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.